# Open CV 16-bit vs 8-bit depth png file has different colors

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

In my program I'm trying to open up various PNG files and add a white background behind the images. When I create a Mat from 16 bit color depth images the colors are skewed when I display them in CvInvoke.imshow. I'm creating Mat objects of the PNG images with CvEnum.ImreadModes. Unchanged because I need to read the values of the alpha channel. The images display correctly without this flag.

8 bit color depth image: [8 bit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plamp.png)

```
Mat imgMat = new Mat(@"filepath", CvEnum.ImreadModes.Unchanged);
Image<Bgra,byte> bgraImg = imgMat.ToImage<Bgra, byte>();

CvInvoke.Imshow("image", bgraImg);
CvInvoke.WaitKey();
```

Result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBDYL.png)

16 bit color depth image: [16 bit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmN6l.png)

```
Mat imgMat = new Mat(@"filepath2", CvEnum.ImreadModes.Unchanged);
Image<Bgra,byte> bgraImg = imgMat.ToImage<Bgra, byte>();

CvInvoke.Imshow("image", bgraImg);
CvInvoke.WaitKey();
```

Result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYFse.png)

I also tried the following to convert 16 bit depth down to 8 bit depth but I got the same result.

```
Mat imgMat = new Mat(@"filepath",CvEnum.ImreadModes.Unchanged);
Mat converted8Bit = imgMat.Clone();
//convert depth
imgMat.ConvertTo(converted8Bit, CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U);
//convert color
Image<Bgra,byte> tempImg = converted8Bit.ToImage<Bgra,byte>();
CvInvoke.CvtColor(tempImg, tempImg, CvEnum.ColorConversion.Rgb2Bgra);
CvInvoke.Imshow("result", tempImg);
CvInvoke.WaitKey();
```

I tried converting the images to 8 bit using CvtColor but got the same result. The expected behavior is both images should load with correct colors.

Comment: In case someone finds this in the future I seem to have found a solution. I don't know WHY it works but it does. I first opened the image as a Bitmap. Then created an Image<Bgra,byte> from the bitmap. Then created a Mat from the image with image.Mat.

Comment: Glad you found your solution. Please create a proper answer and post it to the answer field below. Not every user reads comments and it could help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, there are three simple options:

- Don't use `CvEnum.ImreadModes.Unchanged` - replace `Mat imgMat = new Mat(@"image16bits.png", Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Unchanged);` with:

  ```
   Mat imgMat = new Mat(@"image16bits.png");
  ```

Without using `Unchanged`, the image is automatically converted to 8 bits.
This solution is probably equivalent to the solution from your comment.

- Convert the image to type `Cv8U` after dividing each pixel by 256 (scaling by 1/256):

  ```
   Mat imgMat8bit = new Mat();
   imgMat.ConvertTo(imgMat8bit, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1.0/256.0);
   Image<Bgra, byte> bgraImg = imgMat8bit.ToImage<Bgra, byte>();
  ```
- Set the type of `bgraImg` to `ushort`:

  ```
   Image<Bgra, ushort> bgraImg = imgMat.ToImage<Bgra, ushort>();
  ```

Setting the type to `ushort`, keeps the original 16 bits values, while converting to `byte`, clips the pixel values to 255.

---

The reason for getting white colors is because `Image<Bgra, byte> bgraImg = imgMat8bit.ToImage<Bgra, byte>()` converts the pixels from uint16 (range [0, 65535]) to uint8 (range [0, 255]) without dividing by 256.
The conversion **clips** all the pixels above 255 to 255 (r,g,b=255 applies white color).

---

Code sample for conversion to uint8 with scaling by 1/256:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace Testings
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mat imgMat = new Mat(@"image16bits.png", Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Unchanged);
            Mat imgMat8bit = new Mat();
            imgMat.ConvertTo(imgMat8bit, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1.0/256.0);
            Image<Bgra, byte> bgraImg = imgMat8bit.ToImage<Bgra, byte>();

            CvInvoke.Imshow("image", bgraImg);
            CvInvoke.WaitKey();
        }
    }
}
```